# Error: Can't determine type for tag '<item name="APP_URL" type="String">"https://www.dummyurl_dev.com/"</item>' in build gradleResValues.xml

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I tried to keep my app API URL in **config.properties** in the root folder of the project, and try to read in those value in **module-level build.gradle** file and assign it to ***resValue*** for global access in the application.

but, I am facing an issue. I keep the URL in a property file and try to execute the application based on the build variant, but the compiler will return an error. how to keep the value global?.
Thanks in advance.

Here is what I followed in **build.gradle** to read **config.properties**

```
def configProperties = new Properties()
configProperties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("config.properties")))
```

In ***buildTypes***

```
buildTypes {
          rc {
              resValue("String", "APP_URL", configProperties.getProperty('RC_URL'))
             }
 }
```

In compile time will showing this error

**Error:**
***Build: failed***

***:uimodule:mergeDevResources***

*uimodule/build/generated/res/resValues/dev/values/gradleResValues.xml
Can't determine type for tag '"https://www.dummyurl_dev.com/"'*

**Project-Root path:**
[image: here i created separate property file config.properties]

**Access properties file in build.gradle:**
[image]

**Compiler Error in Build Output**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution for this issue,

Introduce new variable in buildTypes in module-level build.gradle, replace resValue into buildConfigField and pass the arguments like this **`"\"$appUrl\""`** .Here I using ***'RC'*** as build variant instead of ***'dev'*** for this example.

**build.gradle:** *module level*

```
buildTypes {
         rc {
              def appUrl = configProperties['RC_URL']
              buildConfigField("String", "APP_URL", "\"$appUrl\"")
              // following line made this error
              //resValue("String", "APP_URL", configProperties.getProperty('RC_URL'))
            }
}
```

**BuildConfig.java:**
for reference, I added my buildconfig file code here, which is actually done so for.

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.mohan.uimodule";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "rc";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
  

//types of url which i have in config.properties
  public static final String DEV_URL = "https://www.dummyurl_dev.com/";
  public static final String PROD_URL = "https://www.dummyurl_prod.com/";
  public static final String RC_URL = "https://www.dummyurl_rc.com/";

// Fields from build type: rc
  public static final String APP_URL = "https://www.dummyurl_rc.com/";
}
```

Solution:
this is the expected result I got  from **buildconfig.java** and this is my expectation too

```
public static final String APP_URL = "https://www.dummyurl_rc.com/";
```

Hope this answer will help. happy coding, Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

The issue was not with `resValue`, but with the first parameter: this needs to be lower-case:

```
resValue("string", "app_url", "some/app/url")
```

generates `R.string.app_url` like expected.